Jumbled up x axis in power BI?
I have a table with two columns - Period and Rate Increase. Period is data type 'Any' but the values are in the format YYYYMM so 202402 for Feb 2024 and so on.
The source data is an excel file and in the file the Period column is in order (202401 through to 202512). In Transform Data in power BI I have selected the rows I want (>= 202408) and it pulls through the correct rows. However, when I go to plot a simple line graph with Period on the x axis and Rate Increase on the y, the x axis is all jumbled up and it looks as though it is sorting the y axis in descending order. I have not instructed power BI to do this so I don't know how to get it to stop doing it.
I have tried changing the data type of period to both whole number and text in transform data - both should be sortable - but it isn't working. When it's whole number it orders correctly but chooses its own intervals such as 202400, 202450 which is ridiculous considering this is supposed to be a date label (YYYYMM) and I am giving it the damned values. The text type retains the jumbled order.
I could do this in about two seconds in excel, I don't understand why it's so complicated in BI.
I searched online and have been told that a) power BI should retain the source data ordering (it isn't) and b) you can sort the x axis column in transform data (did this, it doesn't work) or by clicking on the Period field in the Data pane and selecting Sort By Column (this doesn't work either).
Please help.
